# Modifying XML from different Tasks simultaneously

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, winforms

I'm trying to run concurrent read- and write operations on an XML file using Tasks. When I use my `FileStream` solution below, a new XML document gets appended to the current, rather than just the `item`. Do I need to clear the document before each new insert? Or do I need to look in to an async XML API?

A simplified example:

```
public static void AddTestElement()
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FilePath);
    XElement item = new XElement("item", "text");

    XElement xmlroot = doc.Element("root");
    if (xmlroot != null)
    {
        xmlroot.Add(item);

        //doc.Save(FilePath); <-- this works, but locks the file

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, 
               FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            doc.Save(fs);
        }
    }
}
```

Called using:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(AddTestElement);
```

Before:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <item>text</item>
</root>
```

After:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <item>text</item>
</root>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <item>text</item>
    <item>text</item>
</root>
```

Comment: I would have solved the problem differently - add the `XElement` nodes to a concurrent collection (for example [ConcurrentBag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and then append with (b)locking and sequentially to the XML still using the `XDocument` object (for example using a mutex). This way the appending and the saving operations are separated from each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the `Task`. It is because you have passed `FileMode.Append` to `FileStream`'s constructoe. Just use `FileMode.Create` and you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't this recreate the file each time I insert a new node?

Comment: No. It loads the last saved file, inserts the new node and saves it again :)

Comment: Ok, just out of curiosity: How about `Filemode.Open`?

Comment: `FileMode.Open` just puts the pointer at the file's beginning, leaving the current content intact. It will do you nothing bad if the new content would be longer (e.g you write 50 bytes on file with 30 bytes length)

Comment: In this special case, you can also use `FileMode.Truncate` because you KNOW the file exists

Comment: But note that all these are for a single-threaded environment. If you want to invoke this method from inside multiple threads simultaneously, you should make it thread-safe :)

Answer (score 2):

**Append:** Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or creates a new file.
**Create:** Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. If the file already exists, it will be overwritten.

In this it will overwrite your file content

**CreateNew :** Specifies that the operating system should create a new file. 
Try the following solution

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ProcessWrite().Wait();
    Console.Write("Done ");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static Task ProcessWrite()
{
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\Srikanth\Desktop\sample.xml";

    return WriteTextAsync(filePath);
}

static async Task WriteTextAsync(string FilePath)
{
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FilePath);
    XElement item = new XElement("item", "text");

    XElement xmlroot = doc.Element("root");


    if (xmlroot != null)
    {
        xmlroot.Add(item);
        //doc.Save(FilePath); <-- this works, but locks the file

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath,
               FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            doc.Save(fs);
        }
    }

}
```